# Choquet Theorem for the cone of non-negative operators

Tags: convex-geometry, convexity

Let $\mathcal B_+$ be the convex cone of bounded non-negative self-adjoint operators on $L^2(\mathbb R)$. With the perspective of applying Choquet's Theorem, I would like to know if the extreme points of $\mathcal B_+$ are known or studied somewhere ?

Comment: Do you want positive self-adjoint operators? I assume you want extreme rays, not only extreme points? I suspect that rank one projections might be the answer.

Comment: @MateuszWasilewski Thanks, I have corrected this.